# Error con git-bisect : Los cambios locales de los siguientes archivos serán sobrescritos

Tags: git

Estoy utilizando git bisect por primera vez.

Este es el history de mi bash:

```
 2005  git bisect start
 2006  git bisect bad
 2007  git lg
 2008  git bisect good 0a5b29b
 2009  history
```

y este es el resultado que me da.

````
error: Los cambios locales de los siguientes archivos serán sobrescritos por checkout:
    db.sqlite
Por favor realiza un commit con los cambios o un stash antes de cambiar ramas.
Abortando```
````

Comment: Eso era muchas gracias.
Era un error tonto pero me lo has solucionado si lo pones como respuesta la doy por buena...
Tal vez hay algo de stackoverflow que no he entendido.¿Por que has decidido poner la respuesta como un comentario en vez de como una respuesta?

Comment: Bueno, a veces cuando la respuesta es tan breve que cabe en un comentario y no estoy del todo seguro de si era ese el problema, lo pongo como comentario. En ocasiones convierto el comentario en respuesta y lo explico más. Un poco mi criterio es: si es un problema que intuyo frecuente y la respuesta puede ayudar a más gente, pongo respuesta. Si es un problema muy específico que posiblemente a nadie más le ocurra, pongo comentario. En este caso no sé muy bien ¿qué opinas tú?

Comment: Que le puede pasar a otro tan despistado como yo.
Es fácil que se te olvide comitear un cambio antes de acudir asustado al bisec a buscar tu error, entonces, si es la primera vez que usas bisect y estas asustado por tu error, entras en pánico con el segundo error, en plan... (¡oh no ahora si que la he liado!) y cuando buscas info del error, como el error no esta directamente relacionado con el bisec no encuentras nada ... hasta que encuentras en stackoverflow la respuesta de abulafia y todo solucionado. ;D

Comment: Vale, me has convencido :-) He convertido el comentario en respuesta y he borrado el original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no está relacionado con `git bisect`.

Simplemente ocurre que tu último comando git necesita hacer un checkout al commit indicado `0a5b29b`. Como con cualquier otro checkout, si tienes archivos que han sido modificados en tu *working dir*, pero aún no han sido actualizados en el repositorio, te avisa antes de "destruirlos" como consecuencia del checkout.

En tu caso, el archivo que va a cambiar es el que contiene tu base de datos. Puedes ignorar el aviso (y perderás los cambios a la base de datos desde el último commit), o guardar ese fichero antes.

Puedes guardarlo con el habitual `git add db.sqlite` seguido de `git commit`, o también, si no quieres que vaya al repositorio, puedes hacer un `git stash` que te guarda todo lo que está pendiente de commit en un almacén temporal llamado el *stash*. Si quieres recuperar el contenido del *stash* haces un `git stash pop`.

Por otro lado, no es buena práctica tener la base de datos en el repositorio. Quizás no deberías haberla metido en primer lugar, sino haberla añadido al `.gitignore` para que no te "moleste" con mensajes de que no está bajo control de versiones. Si no está en el repositorio, tampoco será afectada por hacer `checkout`  a un *commit* previo.